# Monogame sound glitches

Tags: audio, monogame

I have some trouble with sound using monogame 2.5

My app is loading a set of pngs and showing it during render. the loading and rendering is pretty good and fast, but the sound is 'very slow', and full of 'glitches'. It seems that the main thread has not enough time to process the sound.

Diving into the code, i've found this method:

```
public override bool BeforeDraw(GameTime gameTime)        
{ 
// Update our OpenAL sound buffer pools 
soundControllerInstance.Update();            
if (IsPlayingVideo)                return false;
            return true;        
}
```

So, i presume that this method MUST be called 1/33 s.

The problem is that I have to load a new image every 1/12th s, and this process is time-consuming and halts the main thread.

Of course, i've tried to use a background worker, but as i need a `Texture2D` instance, due to `OpenGL` context, i have to load it in the main thread.

I've tried to load the image in the background worker, and create the `Texture2D` in the main thread too, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Oh, my sound is an mp3 sound, but i've tested it with wav, with no results!! :(

Comment: Why do you have to load a new image every 1/12th seconds? It seems strange to me that you'd be doing such a thing. I'd expect all resources to be pre-loaded before the main rendering starts.

Comment: because i have to play video with alpha, and the only 'good' solution i've found is loading, showing and disposing.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the problem was that i was calling `GC.Collect()` every time i changed the texture, and, as i can see, this method blocks EVERYTHING (audio included!!)

I've removed the `GC.Collect()` and now it's working fine!!!

Comment: Calling GC.Collect() is generally a bad idea. The GC is pretty good doing what it does best automatically.